# Simulink: Setting the output of a continuous S-Function

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I have a continuous S-Function that solves the derivatives for various state properties within a ICE cylinder. As such, the output of the function is set to output the integral of those derivatives for each time step which is a 7 element vector (1 for each of the properties being calculated)

```
block.OutputPort(1).Data = block.ContStates.Data;
```

At  some point in the cycle I would like to change the value of this output to an explicit value (i.e. not the integral of the derivative) such as below (in this case the explicit value being x):

```
block.OutputPort(1).Data = block.ContStates.Data;
block.OutputPort(1).Data(3) = x;
```

I'm using a if statement to switch into this alternative output. Through debugging, I think I've verified that Simulink is entering this block of code at the right point - however the output of the S-Function remains as the integral of the  derivatives which gives me a non-finite error.

Any help or suggestions that would allow me to explicitly set the output of a continuous S-Function would be much appreciated.